# Can't send email using Mandrill API from local apache server

Tags: php, codeigniter, api, email, mandrill

I am trying to send email from my localhost using mandrill api, but everytime i call the send email function, i get the status 'queued'. If i see the mandrill api log, i see that the call was successful, also i do not get any email. Here is the code I am using--

```
     try {
        $mandrill         = new Mandrill($this->api_key);
        $template_name    = 'Invitation';
        $template_content = array(
            array(
                'name'    => 'main',
                'content' => 'Hi *|FIRSTNAME|*, you are cordially invited.'
            )
        );
        $message          = array(
            'html'                      => '<p>Example HTML content</p>',
            'text'                      => 'Example text content',
            'subject'                   => 'example subject',
            'from_email'                => 'message.from_email@example.com',
            'from_name'                 => 'Example Name',
            'to'                        => array(
                array(
                    'email' => 'someone@somemail.com',
                    'name'  => 'Recipient Name',
                    'type'  => 'to'
                )
            ),
            'headers'                   => array('Reply-To' => 'someother@anothermail.com'),
            'important'                 => false,
            'track_opens'               => null,
            'track_clicks'              => null,
            'auto_text'                 => null,
            'auto_html'                 => null,
            'inline_css'                => null,
            'url_strip_qs'              => null,
            'preserve_recipients'       => null,
            'view_content_link'         => null,
            'bcc_address'               => 'someone@somemail.com',
            'tracking_domain'           => null,
            'signing_domain'            => null,
            'return_path_domain'        => null,
            'merge'                     => true,
            'merge_language'            => 'mailchimp',
            'global_merge_vars'         => array(
                array(
                    'name'    => 'merge1',
                    'content' => 'merge1 content'
                )
            ),
            'merge_vars'                => array(
                array(
                    'rcpt' => 'another@anothermail.pro',
                    'vars' => array(
                        array(
                            'name'    => 'FIRSTNAME',
                            'content' => 'My First Name'
                        )
                    )
                )
            ),
            'tags'                      => array('password-resets'),
            'subaccount'                => 'customer-123',
            'google_analytics_domains'  => array('example.com'),
            'google_analytics_campaign' => 'message.from_email@example.com',
            'metadata'                  => array('website' => 'www.example.com'),
            'recipient_metadata'        => array(
                array(
                    'rcpt'   => 'recipient.email@example.com',
                    'values' => array('user_id' => 123456)
                )
            ),
            'attachments'               => array(
                array(
                    'type'    => 'text/plain',
                    'name'    => 'myfile.txt',
                    'content' => 'ZXhhbXBsZSBmaWxl'
                )
            ),
            'images'                    => array(
                array(
                    'type'    => 'image/png',
                    'name'    => 'IMAGECID',
                    'content' => 'ZXhhbXBsZSBmaWxl'
                )
            )
        );
        $async            = false;
        $ip_pool          = 'Main Pool';
        $send_at          = '2014-11-02 01:11:13 PM';
        $result           = $mandrill->messages->sendTemplate($template_name, $template_content, $message, $async, $ip_pool, $send_at);
        print_r($result);
```

I am trying to find a solution but still no hope. (this is my first time using mandrill api). Am i doing anything wrong?

Comment: try with the codeigniter email library its quite easy to send email from localhost and it will work 100%

Comment: I know, but my requirement is to use mandrill.... thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a `subaccount` specified, but probably don't have a subaccount with that name. Consider removing any optional parameters that you're not actually specifying to ensure that things are working as expected. Similarly, you've got a scheduled time, attachments and images, but those are samples, so you probably want to exclude them. When you include attachments, the message will be processed asynchronously; removing the sample ones will surface more errors since the message shouldn't be processed asynchronously anymore.

Comment: if only you could provide this answer 34 hours ago, i could have saved this long time :-(. Whatever i have solved the issue without knowing the problem and now i know form your answer.